# React / Redux - is a function prop for deferred state loading in mapStateToProps bad?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Divider } from "antd";
import MovieList from "../components/MovieList";
import IncreaseCountButton from "../components/IncreaseCountButton";
import DeleteButton from "../components/DeleteButton";
import { deleteMovie, increaseCount } from "../actions/movies";
import { getIsDeleting, getIsIncreasing } from "../reducers/actions";

export class MovieListContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleIncrease = this.handleIncrease.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    isIncreasing: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isDeleting: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  async handleIncrease(movie) {
    await this.props.increaseCount(movie, this.props.token);
  }

  async handleDelete(movie) {
    await this.props.deleteMovie(movie.id, this.props.token);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MovieList movies={this.props.movies}>
        {(text, movie) => (
          <div>
            <IncreaseCountButton
              onIncrease={() => this.handleIncrease(movie)}
              loading={this.props.isIncreasing(movie.id)}
            />
            <Divider type="vertical" />
            <DeleteButton
              onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(movie)}
              loading={this.props.isDeleting(movie.id)}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </MovieList>
    );
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isIncreasing: id => getIsIncreasing(state, id),
  isDeleting: id => getIsDeleting(state, id),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteMovie, increaseCount }
)(MovieListContainer);
```

I feel like this might be bad for performance/reconciliation reasons, but not sure how else to retrieve the state in a way that hides implementation details.

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/vitalicwow/140c06a52dd9e2e062b2917f5c741727

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can handle these asynchronous actions with redux. You can use thunk to perform 2 actions and can store a flag to determine what is being done to an object (Deleting, Changing, etc):

action

```
export const deleteMovieAction = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "MOVIE_DELETING", id });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "MOVIE_DELETED", id });
    }, 2000);
  };
};
```

reducer

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MOVIE_DELETING": {
      const movies = [...state.movies];
      movies.find(x => x.id === action.id).isDeleting = true;
      return { ...state, movies };
    }
    case "MOVIE_DELETED": {
      const movies = state.movies.filter(x => x.id !== action.id);
      return { ...state, movies };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k3jnv01ymv

An alternative is to separate out the ids into a new array that are being deleted

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MOVIE_DELETING": {
      const movieDeletingIds = [...state.movieDeletingIds, action.id];
      return { ...state, movieDeletingIds };
    }
    case "MOVIE_DELETED": {
      const movieDeletingIds = state.movieDeletingIds.filter(
        x => x.id !== action.id
      );
      const movies = state.movies.filter(x => x.id !== action.id);
      return { ...state, movieDeletingIds, movies };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mj52w4y3zj

(This code should be cleaned up, but is just to demo using thunk)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did contemplate that solution but I prefer not to add extra properties to my entities (movies), which is why I went with a separate table to store pending actions. Accessing the separate table in the cleanest way possible is essentially what my question boils down to.

Comment: That is basically my current solution, it doesn't answer the question which was about my selectors in mapStateToProps and whether that is an okay thing to do. Sorry if it's not clear. In your Movies component you have things like `movieDeletingIds.includes(movie.id)` which shouldn't really be in the component but in a selector alongside the reducer.

Comment: If you don't wish to have that logic, then you must go with option 1 I provided. If it is acceptable then option 2. You can use `reselect`, but essentially it will be doing the same thing

Comment: I do have the logic in the getIsIncreasing/getIsDeleting selectors, I just want to know if it's okay to add them to the props in this way.

Comment: Yes, it is ok. See reselect documentation for similar examples
https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect